# Google Map: Download lon/lat of a route/trace

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My question is if I can download lat/lon information of a complete trace on google map or if there is an external library to do it.

E.g for the bus number 336, following is the trace. I want to download it so that I have this information. Is it possible?

[image: Trace for a bus]

Btw I took the trace from this [link](http://www.haltestellen-buslinien.de/stadt-dortmund_nrw/buslinie-336__luetgendortmund-s-bahnhof-dortmund). Sharing this incase somebody has hack with inspect element or something.

Thanks a lot guys.

Fact is that this information is available since its displayed.

How do I get it. There has to be away.

** EDIT **
Why did this get downvoted. Please tell? What else am I supposed to do?

Comment: Did you try `view-source` on that page?

Comment: yes tried this but to no avail

Comment: I see points in `view-source`, what do you mean by "to no avail"?